# Wi-fi disconnect every 5 minutes (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, adapter

I installed ElementaryOS and noticed a problem with the wifi disconnecting constantly regardless of what I did. Thinking it was the OS I installed Ubuntu **16.04.3** and the same problem perseveres. The wifi says I'm connected while I have no internet and then it disconnect and comes back whenever it pleases. Nothing I do impacts how quickly it comes back. I have tried
`Power Management: Off`, `modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`, `service network-manger restart`, **rtlwifi_new** make and install, disabling IPv6. My network adapter is **RTL8821AE**. I would appreciate any answers from people who have dealt with this bug.

Comment: Use `journalctl --follow`, and wait for the disconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This is definitely a problem with the kernel or OS, **after upgrading Ubuntu to 17.04** there is now no drops in connectivity and only very rare 5 second delays to loading websites. Make sure you install the new Realtek drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git 
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

I then recommend rebooting.
After rebooting run:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ae
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

If you have a different network adapter replace rtl8821ae with your adapter. I'm happy to answer any questions if anyone's having difficulty.